# How can I change the font used in Preview PDF notes?

Tags: pdf, preview

As of Mountain Lion, Preview has been "upgraded" with a ridiculous font choice for its Notes (Control-Command-N). I use them all the time in PDF files and suffer from the Comic Sans feeling of Marker Felt.

**Is it possible to change the font used by Preview to show notes?**

It does not seem that the question has already been asked.

Comment: I have finally upgraded to ML and just noticed. This is RIDICULOUS. My quick google search has not turned up any solution so far, hope somebody will help here...

Comment: I second the ridiculousness of the current situation.

Comment: You can view all of your annotations (including plain notes) in the Inspector, where they appear in a less maddening font.

Comment: The only explanation I can find is that nobody at Apple is actually using that feature, otherwise someone would have noticed and asked why notes do not use a generic font like Lucida Grande.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, it is *not* possible to change the font used by Preview for Notes - this is denoted by Apple an 'UnEditable'.

[This thread on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4543387?start=0&tstart=0) (which I can't take credit for) provides a couple of work arounds such as using Annotations instead of notes (as these *are* editable) or post-editing comments in Adobe Acrobat Reader XI, but not an actual solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had missed that thread as I was searching for notes specifically... Feedback to Apple sent, hope this can be changed... Annotation it is for now then, or switch back to Skim...

Answer (score 5):

Go to Font Book, select Noteworthy, right click and show the font file in Finder. Alternatively you can directly navigate to `/System/Library/Fonts`

Replace the extension of the Noteworthy font file with `.disabled` (or `.bak`, or anything else non-font related). Make sure with the Inspector that the extension has not been re-added by the Finder. This is how it should look:

[image: Disabled font Noteworthy]

Re-start Preview, all PDF notes are now shown in Helvetica.

Tested on 10.8 and 10.9.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and receive the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method of editing the font file directly is no longer applicable in the newest OSX because those files are read-only and it probably won't be wise to mess them.

Try Adobe Reader instead?